# How to do Groupby and map in one go in python just like we do in scala

Tags: python-3.x, scala

we have a list in Scala :

```
val testList = List("Sita" -> 1, "Sita" -> 2, "Ram" -> 3, "Ram" -> 4, "Shyam" -> 5)
```

I applied this on list to group the values by key in Scala:

```
val res = testList.groupBy(_._1).map { case (k, v) => k -> v.map(_._2).sum }
```

and i got this as a result:

```
Map(Shyam -> 5, Ram -> 7, Sita -> 3)
```

**I want to do the same in python Please help me out:**

```
testList = [("Sita", 1), ("Sita", 2), ("Ram", 3), ("Ram", 4), ("Shyam", 5)]
```

**Edit: And what if i have a list like this:**

```
testList = [("Sita_English", 1), ("Sita_Maths", 2), ("Ram_English", 3), ("Ram_Maths", 4), ("Shyam_English", 5)]
```

Comment: You should not modify your question after it got answered. Furthermore, it is nearly the same.

Comment: Can you please help me with how to split the Edit of my question and then get the required answer........@BlueSheepToken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to have a solution in functional way:

```
out = list(map(lambda v:(v[0], sum(map(lambda s: s[1], v[1]))), groupby(testList, key=lambda x: x[0])))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i wanted

Answer (score 3):

```
testList = [("Sita", 1), ("Sita", 2), ("Ram", 3), ("Ram", 4), ("Shyam", 5)]

from itertools import groupby

out = {v: sum(i[1] for i in g)  for v, g in groupby(testList, lambda k: k[0])}

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'Sita': 3, 'Ram': 7, 'Shyam': 5}
```

A little explanation:

`itertools.groupby()` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)) returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable. In this case the iterable is `tesList`. The key function `lambda k: k[0]` returns first element of the tuple -> so we are grouping along the first element.

The dict comprehension is using this first element as a key and second elements from the group as parameter to the `sum()` function.

EDIT: Using only `map()`:

```
testList = [("Sita", 1), ("Sita", 2), ("Ram", 3), ("Ram", 4), ("Shyam", 5)]

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

out = dict(map(lambda v:(v[0], sum(map(itemgetter(1), v[1]))), groupby(testList, itemgetter(0))))
print(out)
```

Comment: is it possible to write using 'map' instead of 'for'

Comment: @abhishekhmishra Of course, yes. See my edit. But using for/dict/set-comprehensions is considered more "pythonic" than using `map/filter/reduce`.

Comment: Please help me with the edit in the question and please give me some reference to learn python ...that will be a great help...Thanks a lot for the help...

Comment: @abhishekhmishra There's beginners guide to Python on official site: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide